# postgreSQL aggregate functions without sort

Tags: postgresql, sorting, aggregate-functions, temporary-files

Looking at EXPLAIN query, I notice that sorting is done when aggregate functions are executed. Can aggregate functions (or custom aggregate functions) be run without sorting. I want to avoid sort because I'm working on huge database and the aggregate function is creating huge temporary file (probably because of the sorting). I don't have enough space to store the temp file and hence not able to execute the query.

thanks,

Comment: [edit] your question and add the table definition (including all indexes), the query and the output of `explain analyze`. Formatted text please, no screen shots. If you can't run `explain analyze` then at least the output of a simple `explain`

Comment: Which aggregate function(s)? I don't think any of the common ones would require a sort at all.